# Изменение цвета фона консольного приложения в С++

Tags: c++, консоль, background

Как задать цвет тексту я знаю через `SetConsoleTextAttribute`, это как-то быстро далось, а вот именно фон, как-то не дается. Пробовал вариант с `system("color  номер нужного цвета");`, но как-то все не то что нужно получается. Задача у меня такая, чтоб пользователь сам выбирал и цвет текста и цвет фона, а результат уже в консоль.
Мне не нужно решение, хочу сам понять. Перерыл весь MSDN, что-то я там так и не нашел. Дайте пожалуйста, ссылку на нужный ресурс или подскажите в целом, куда смотреть? Google облазил вдоль и поперек, но не попалось ничего из того что нужно, те варианты, мне не подходят. По-идее, так как задача простая, решение тоже долно быть простым.
Работаю в Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Цвет фона всей консоли или цвет фона под отдельными участками текста?

Comment: С помощью `SetConsoleTextAttribute` также можно менять цвет фона

Comment: @Croessmah всей консоли

Comment: @acade значит, что-то упустил, спасибо, сейчас еще рез пересмотрю все что касается `SetConsoleTextAttribute`

Comment: @VladSpirin, разобрались с вопросом?

Comment: @acade если честно, не до конца. Есть вопросы и сомнения. Вы имели ввиду что-то такое: `SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_BLUE);`? Если такой вариант, то как задать, чтоб пользователь сам мог выбрать? Тут получается, что я задаю текст и фон вместе. Дело в том, так как я на курсах еще функции по программе не проходил, а задание вот такое, значит тут или через if или switch использовать. Вариантов не много.

Comment: Еще думал про `enum`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

HANDLE hout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);  // получение дескриптора
                                                // окна консоли

// перечисление доступных цветов
enum class color : unsigned short
{
    black, blue, green, cyan, red, magenta, brown, lightgray, darkgray,
    lightblue, lightgreen, lightcyan, lightred, lightmagenta, yellow, white
};

// меняет цвет в консоли на указанный
// foreground - цвет текста
// background - цвет фона
void set_col(color foreground, color background)
{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(
        hout,   // дескриптор окна консоли в котором необходимо изменить цвет
        ((short)background << 4) | (short)foreground); // флаг
    // в котором закодирован необходимые цвета

    // (short)background << 4 - приводим к типу short и смещаем на 4 бита влево
    // (short)foreground - приводим к типу short и объединяем бинарным или |
}   

int main()
{
    set_col(color::green, color::white);
    std::cout << "Green text on white background";
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

На счет обработки ввода пользователя: тут на выбор, как реализовывать. Пользователь может вводить строку. Потом грубым перебором if-ом. Можно добавить `std::map<std::string, color>`. Пользователь может также вводить число (но это не юзер-френдли).

Answer (score 3):

Если не хочешь разбираться с `<windows.h>`, то могу предложить решение с `system`:

```
string color = "color 0F";

    while (true)
    {
        system("cls");

        cout << "Choose color: " << endl << endl;

        cout << "\t0 — черный" << endl;
        cout << "\t1 — синий" << endl;
        cout << "\t2 — зеленый" << endl;
        cout << "\t3 — голубой" << endl;
        cout << "\t4 — красный" << endl;
        cout << "\t5 — лиловый" << endl;
        cout << "\t6 — желтый" << endl;
        cout << "\t7 — белый" << endl;
        cout << "\t8 — серый" << endl;
        cout << "\t9 — свело - синий" << endl;
        cout << "\tA — светло - зеленый" << endl;
        cout << "\tB — светло - голубой" << endl;
        cout << "\tС — светло - красный" << endl;
        cout << "\tD — ярко - розовый" << endl;
        cout << "\tE — светло - желтый" << endl;
        cout << "\tF — ярко - белый" << endl;

        char ch = _getch();

        if (ch > 47 && ch < 58)     // ввод для цифр
        {
            color[6] = ch;
            system(color.c_str());
        }
        else if (ch > 96 && ch < 103)       // ввод для строчных букв
        {
            color[6] = ch;
            system(color.c_str());
        }
        else if (ch > 64 && ch < 71)        // ввод для заклавных букв
        {
            color[6] = ch;
            system(color.c_str());
        }

        if (ch == 27)
            break;
    }
```

Ну и цвет текста аналогично.

Собственно, задачу решает. Если что не так понял - извиняй)

Comment: Вместо кодов символов можно писать сами символы между апострофами...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat точно)